# Combine two columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have 15 csv files whose one of the column represents year. Problem is that the year column is named 'year' in some files and 'year_' in the other. So I have two columns that have the same information to me but since each file has only one of the column name(either year or year_), if row 1 has value in 'year', 'year_' has NaN. I want to combine those two columns so that I can get rid of NaN. What is the best way to do this?

Before

```
       year     year_
 1     NaN      1999
 2     2002     NaN
 3     2000     NaN
 .
 .
 .
 N     NaN      2004
```

I want this to be

After

```
       year
 1     1999
 2     2002
 3     2000
 .
 .
 .
 N     2004
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) function.

```
df['YEAR'] = df['year'].combine_first(df['year_'])
```

where `df['year']` will be default and `df['year2']` will be used to fill null values.

Comment: Seems to be faster than the `sum` solution.

Comment: @HirotakaNakagame: Glad that we could help. Please also upvote helpful answers and accept the one that helped you most to show others that your issue is solved (you can do so by clicking on the small check next to the answer which then turns green).

Answer (score 2):

Given that only one has a valid value, you can simply sum them on axis 1

```
year_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('year')]
df['year'] = df[year_cols].sum(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as [@Vaishali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47802450/1534017): you can just sum the year columns; use `filter` to select the columns:

```
df.filter(like='year').sum(axis=1)
```